# What does EPS stand for?

Tags: star-trek

I often hear the abbreviation EPS on Star Trek (EPS Grid, EPS Conduit, etc). 
I know it relates to the ship’s energy systems, but I'm not sure I’ve ever heard anyone say what it actually *is*.

So what do the letters **EPS** actually stand for?

Answer (score 26):

I believe it stands for [Electro-plasma system](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Electro-plasma_system)

> The electro-plasma system (EPS for short, or more specifically the electro-plasma distribution network, as engineers like to call it) is the primary form of energy distribution on starships.
>
> The technology is based on storing energy in a highly energetic plasma, "electro-plasma," and distributing it throughout the ship via plasma conduits, called EPS conduits. The system of conduits is also referred to as the plasma grid. EPS conduits usually start at a matter-antimatter reaction assembly, also called the warp core, where matter is converted to energy, and extend to all areas of a ship. Plasma conduit power levels are regulated by plasma coolant ducts, and monitored by plasma conversion sensors.

Here is more information on those [conduits](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/EPS_conduit)

And here is an image of a Secondary Plasma System

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is the **E**lectro **P**lasma **S**ystem (also known as the **Electroplasma System**), a series of conduits that travel around the ship providing charged plasma power to vital systems.

A secondary power system also provides electrical energy although very few systems use this largely outdated technology.

**The [TNG Technical Manual](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation_Technical_Manual) defines it thusly;**

> **MAJOR UTILITIES NETWORKS**
>   *Power transmission for onboard systems is accomplished by a network of microwave power transmission waveguides known as the electro plasma
>   system (EPS). Major power supplies derive microwave power from the
>   warp propulsion power conduits and the main impulse engines.
>   Additional feeds draw power from the saucer module impulse engines as
>   well as a number of auxiliary fusion generators. A secondary power
>   distribution system provides electrical power for specialized
>   requirements.*

And it's mentioned in several episodes, albeit never by its full name:

> **NOG:** *No! I have to listen at precisely eighty two decibels because that's the volume Worf listens at! Of course, if I could've
>   simply told him why I needed **two metres of electro-plasma conduit**
>   from the Defiant, he probably would've just given it to me and things
>   would be a lot quieter around here!* <sub><sup>[DS9 : In the Cards](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/523.htm)</sup></sub>

and

> **DATA:** ***The primary plasma system*** does not indicate a power drain from any of the transporters.
>
> **LAFORGE:** *Then whoever used the transporter must have bypassed the primary feeds.*
>
> **DATA:** *Tracking power from secondary systems. No surges to any of the transporters indicated.* <sub><sup>[TNG : The Mind's Eye](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/198.htm)</sup></sub>

Answer (score -3):

electrical power systems . eps conduit means the mains is run through plastic pipe white above ground to stop uv damage and orange bellow ground .

Comment: Any evidence for this?

Comment: How much ground is there on a starship under which to bury this orange conduit?